# Is this PDE $xu_x-yu_y=u$ Well posed?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, problem-solving, linear-pde

We have the given problem

$$xu_x-yu_y=u,\ x>0, \ y>0 \  (1)$$
$$u(x,x)=x^2, \ x>0, \ (2)$$

They ask to check if the problem is well-posed and solve it next.

I know that a problem is well-posed if:

1. It has a solution
2. The solution is unique
3. A small change to PDE/side conditions produce only small changes in the solution.

Also, we can observe that the PDE is linear, first order and homogeneous if we write it in the form
$$xu_x-yu_y-u=0,\ x>0, \ y>0 \  (1)$$
$$u(x,x)=x^2, \ x>0, \ (2)$$

With characteristic curves

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{x} \frac{dx}{dt}=1$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-y \Leftrightarrow -\frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dt}=1 $$ and

$$\frac{du}{dt}=u \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{u} \frac{du}{dt}=1$$

From which we obtain :$\begin{cases}
yx=c_1 \\
\frac{u}{x}=c_2 \\
\end{cases}$

Combine the forms:
$$c_2=G(c_1) \Leftrightarrow \frac{u}{x}=G(xy)\Leftrightarrow u=xG(yx)$$

Now, using the initial condition $u(x,x)=x^2$ gives
$$x^2=xG(x*x) \Leftrightarrow G(x^2)=x $$

**So, how could I check if it is well-posed before solving it? And if yes!!! How? Any suggestion?**

Comment: Your analysis suggests that $G(x)=\sqrt{x}\,.$ Then from
$$
u=x\sqrt{xy}\,,\quad\partial_xu=\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{xy}\,,\quad\partial_yu=\frac{x^2}{2\sqrt{xy}}\,,
$$
you can see that this $u$ satisfies the PDE and the condition (2). What did you mean by well-posed?

Comment: @KurtG. 1. it has a solution
 2. the solution is unique
 3. a small change to PDE/side conditions produce only small changes in the solution. Could I show that before solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question itself is ill-posed. This is not a general boundary value problem or initial value problem. It is a specific request which you can explicitly solve. (You already solved it, actually, as [noted by Kurt in comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4606642/is-this-pde-xu-x-yu-y-u-well-posed#comment9707604_4606642)).

A correct well-posedness question would be something like:
consider the PDE $x\partial_x u-y\partial_y u=u$ with the "boundary condition" $u(x, x)=\phi(x)$, where $\phi$ belongs to the space $X$. (This $X$ must be a topological space of functions. Typically it will be a Hilbert or Banach space). Is this problem well-posed **in this space**?

> If you don't specify the topology, how can you say whether the solution depends continuously on the data?

For the given problem, however, there is something that remains to be done even without specifying topologies. **Is the solution unique**? You found one, but how can you be sure it is the only one? Most probably, this is what you are supposed to do (here I am assuming that the problem comes from an assignment).

Comment: Could you take a look to my consideration below?

Comment: It is not only an assignment, but I am trying to understand fully this section of PDE because it will be part of my thesis for my master next year

Comment: Good luck with your studies

Comment: Thank you for your wishes and your help

Answer (score 0):

To check for the existence of a unique solution to the above problem, we will need  the tangent vector at each point $(x,y)$ of the characteristic projections which is
$$\tau=(\frac{dx}{dt},\frac{dy}{dt})=(x,-y)$$

The data curve is

$$C=\{(x,y,u) \in (0,+\infty)\times(0,+\infty)\times(0,+\infty):x=t,y=t,u=t^2,t \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

The perpendicular vector in C is
$$n=(\frac{dy}{dt},-\frac{dx}{dt})=(1,-1)$$

and $$n \cdot t=x+y$$ and if $n \cdot t\neq0$, the problem is well posed.

Is my consideration right?

Comment: What? What are you trying to do now? How is this an answer to your own question?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro   if $\tau *n \neq 0$ then the problem has unique solution. Right?

Comment: I can't follow your reasoning. First, you should edit this answer, explaining why it is an answer to the question, and then also explain carefully what you are doing. Finally, don't use $\ast$ for multiplication (it's $\cdot$, \cdot) and don't use $X$ for Cartesian product (it's $\times$, \times).

Comment: Much better now.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro in this particular case the problem give us that $x>0,y>0$ so $\tau \cdot n \neq 0$. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. I don't know why this proves uniqueness, I do not have the method of characteristics so fresh in my mind like you have, but I kind of sense this is correct.